# Persist Star Rating and Comments to the google play store

Tags: android, google-play, persistence, ratingbar

I'm currently implementing a rate-it feature in an app.

So I'll have a simple dialog with 2 buttons, `rate-it` and `no thanks`, if the user clicks `rate-it` they are shown another dialog with a Rating Bar and a edittext to leave a comment. Upon clicking OK they are taken to the play-store via

```
  context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" +
                                    APP_PACKAGE)))
```

However I don't know how to bundle up their rating and comment and apply to my app's rating fields within the google play store. Is this even possible on Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can pass the ratings from within your app to Google Play.

If anything like that existed, then everybody would've misused it by having a check in their app like,

```
if(rating>=4){ 
    sendDataToPlayStore()
}else{
    takeFeedbackFromUser() 
}
```

That would naturally inflate apps ratings in Play Store, which is not what Play Store is aiming for.

So no, it's not possible, and I can definitely say that it wont be possible in near future to avoid spam.

Comment: So I understand the problem with submitting a rating from WITHIN the app. However, maybe i'm failing to understand the problem with gather the user's feedback from within the app, then when they click `rate-it` they will be taken to the play store with these fields filled out, from there they must click SUBMIT to actually submit the review. How would this inflate the ratings? The developer has no control over the rating, simply make the process streamlined from the user. This is a sidebar question but still related

Comment: ignore the previous comment, I understand the problem. The developer could simple choose to not send the bad ratings to the play store and only the good ones. Thanks for your help

Comment: That's what I'm saying, if developer is given the chance to actually be able to send the user data to Play Store, developers will add a simple check, like if they only rate good in their own app, they will send them to Play Store to rate, and if they give bad ratings, they'll only take feedback from user. They'll be able to selectively forward the users to play store with what you're saying